# Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "WebDriverAgentRunner" target's entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, appium-ios

Xcode is showing below error message while enabling automatic sign in option. How to fix this issue ?

> Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the
>   "WebDriverAgentRunner" target's entitlements.
>
> Switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a
>   matching provisioning profile from the developer website.
>   Alternatively, to continue using automatic signing, remove these
>   entitlements from your entitlements file and their associated
>   functionality from your code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error message states it clear:

> Switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a matching
>   provisioning profile from the developer website

I suggest you checking Official Appium docs about the manual setup:

http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/

Make sure you got an active Apple developer account and have access to provision profile your app was signed. Use the same profile for WebDriverAgent signing and it should be working fine.

Comment: Already an issue has been raised in appium io

https://discuss.appium.io/t/automatic-signing-is-unable-to-resolve-an-issue-with-the-webdriveragentrunner-targets-entitlements/25516/4

Have tried Manual Configuration as well but no use. Were you able to overcome this error?

Comment: Yes, it works for me without any problem. FYI I'm using Dev Account provided by my company, no a personal one.

Answer (score 0):

I've also got this problem at last week. But I didn't found any solution.

At present, using the developer account can solve this problem.